# ¿Problema cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol usando la API PHP de Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, time, real-time

Mi problema es que trato de acceder a mi base de datos en tiempo real alojada en Firebase usando su api rest [kreait/firebase](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage-example) versión 4.18 en **PHP**, pero al momento en que el programa trata de procesar el .json o credencial de acceso me lanza este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL
>   error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   oauth2.googleapis.com:443 (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:185
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(149):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(102):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzle in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\QueryException.php
>   on line 38

**Nuevo error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
>   error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400
>   Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token
>   (60 minutes) and in (truncated...) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66):
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203):
>   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>
> ## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156):
>
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1,
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::Guzz in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\QueryException.php
>   on line 38

Al ejecutar este **codigo** en el metodo `_construct()` de mi clase:

```
private $serviceAccount;
private $firebase;
private $database;

function __construct(){
    $this->serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json');

    $this->firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($this->serviceAccount)
        // The following line is optional if the project id in your credentials file
        // is identical to the subdomain of your Firebase project. If you need it,
        // make sure to replace the URL with the URL of your project.
        ->withDatabaseUri('https://bot-whatsapp-1d730.firebaseio.com/')
        ->create();
    $this->database= $this->firebase->getDatabase();
}
```

Y la investigación que realice me arrojo que puede ser un error o problema relacionado con mi tiempo de servidor o ya que estoy trabajando usando XAMPP (localhost), este deberá ser mi tiempo de equipo (¿creo?). Pero en ambas fuentes que obtuve solucionaron su problema modificando su tiempo, uno [cambio la hora de su equipo](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/270) (conveniente para mi) y otro [el tiempo de su servidor o host](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/163). Ambas fuentes las obtuve desde GitHub.

Pero no entiendo completamente como ellos pudieron determinar como debían cambiar el tiempo, es decir, como determinaron la diferencia de tiempo para luego corregirla y poder trabajar en conjunto a firebase.

Soy un programador reciente en PHP, soy mas de Java, disculpen mi ignorancia. Gracias y espero su apoyo.

Comment: No creo que sea ese el problema. Al menos el error no habla nada de eso, el motivo que indica es el siguiente: *`cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection`*  Eso no creo que tenga que ver con el tiempo. ¿Estás usando `cURL`? Sería bueno que compartas cómo envías la petición `cURL`. El error puede deberse a una petición mal escrita, o a que has superado los límites de consulta ( [ver aquí](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) ) o cosas así. Sería bueno que revises posibles errores en la consola de proyectos de Google.

Comment: Amigo hasta donde conozco estoy usando la lapi rest de php. No se si esta utiliza alguna petición en cURL por su cuenta.

Comment: Este es el link de documentación https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage-example y estoy usando la versión 4.18

Comment: [Revisa esta solución](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/843#issuecomment-287580872) y todas las demás planteadas en ese hilo, donde se trata el problema específico para la API que estás usando. Parece que el error viene por un problema de certificado y debes colocar un archivo de certificado en el directorio correcto. Los errores SSL por lo general son por motivos como ese. No creo que tenga nada que ver con el tiempo de tu servidor.

Comment: **[Mira también aquí](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html?highlight=pem#curl-error-xx)**. Es la **documentación oficial** de la API que usas. Dicen que cuando hay problemas de cURL tienes que verificar si tienes los certificados e indican cómo hacerlo. En resumen, sería ejecutar este comando: `var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());` y verificar si en la clave `default_cert_file` está algo parecido a `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`. Si no está ese archivo, tienes que descargarlo (ellos indican el enlace) y ponerlo en la carpeta por defecto de certificados.

Comment: Yo había descartado esta solución ya que yo había instalado el **cert.pem**, pero lo que no hice fue reiniciar mi Apache, gracias, pero el error persiste, aunque cambio y ahora es el mismo presentado en las fuentes publicadas. ya actualice mi pregunta.

Comment: No, **ese error no persiste**. Lo que te aparece ahora es **otro error** y además muy diferente. Sugiero que nos centremos en plantear cada caso aparte, porque este sitio está pensado para que pueda servir a otras personas con el mismo problema. Escribiré una respuesta con la solución al problema del cURL y plantea el nuevo problema en otra pregunta. Lo que parece indicar el nuevo error es que estás armando mal tu petición.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo publique su respuesta he iniciare una nueva pregunta para el nuevo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[La documentación de la API que estás usando](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html?highlight=pem#curl-error-xx) indica que cuando hay errores de `cURL`, los mismos se deben a algún problema con el certificado:

> Si recibe un error `cURL XX: ...`, asegúrese de tener un paquete de
>   Certificados CA Root actuales en su sistema y de que PHP lo use.

Para hacer dicha revisión hay que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Verificar el estado de los certificados mediante: `var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());`
2. Saldrá algo como esto:

   ```
   array(8) {
       'default_cert_file' =>
       string(32) "/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem"
       'default_cert_file_env' =>
       string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
       'default_cert_dir' =>
       string(29) "/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs"
       'default_cert_dir_env' =>
       string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
       'default_private_dir' =>
       string(31) "/usr/local/etc/openssl/private"
       'default_default_cert_area' =>
       string(23) "/usr/local/etc/openssl"
       'ini_cafile' =>
       string(0) ""
       'ini_capath' =>
       string(0) ""
   }
   ```
3. Hay que revisar si el archivo dado en el campo `default_cert_file` existe realmente. Crea una copia de seguridad del archivo, descargua el paquete de CA actual de https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem y ponlo en la ruta que indica `default_cert_file`.

#### Otra solución alternativa

Si el problema persiste, otra solución posible es configurar `curl.cainfo` en el archivo `php.ini`:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = /absolute/path/to/cacert.pem
```

Conviene reiniciar el servidor.

Si el problema persiste, revisar las diferentes soluciones planteadas [en este hilo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/843).