# Gmail API - PHP Fatal error: certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, api, gmail

estoy tratando de conectar e iniciar la API de Gmail.
Para ello estoy usando la guía [quickstart en PHP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php)
Están listos todos primeros 3 pasos sin problemas, pero al momento de usar `php quickstart.php` ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Primero, usando el comando `php quickstart.php` en la terminal, ejecutamos el quickstart.
2. Nos envía un link, el cual hacemos ingreso, y permitimos el acceso al correo
3. Como respuesta, nos entrega un código de verificación que hay que pegar de vuelta en la terminal

Pero al momento de realizar esos pasos, y luego de pegar dicho codigo, salta el siguiente error:
Probablemente, sea algún problema de instalación, pero no se como confirmarlo.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL 
certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate 
(see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) 
in C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187

Stack trace:
#0 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHt in C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see 
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHt in C:\AppServ\www\gmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Problema cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol usando la API PHP de Firebase?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/258711/29967).

Comment: Ya está respondida, solo que aun no puedo marcarla

Comment: Tienes que esperar un tiempo para poder marcarla. La enlacé con la otra, porque en la respuesta se explica este mismo modo de resolver el problema, y también un modo alternativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de una búsqueda, lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

1. Descargar el último `cacert.pem` desde
   https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Agregar a `php.ini` la siguiente línea, o editarla si ya existe:
    curl.cainfo="/ubicacion del archivo/cacert.pem" (Entre comillas dobles)
3. Reiniciar Apache, se puede usando STOP y START desde inicio.